# Command prompt special characters

Tags: linux, bash

When setting the value of the primary command prompt (PS1) the followig two cases

```
export PS1="\u"
export PS1="\\u"
```

gives the same result:

```
root
```

as a command prompt string.
How does the `\u` and `\\u` differs if the both results is identical? Shouldn't the `\\u` outputs just `\u` since `\\` denotes backslash itself?

Comment: Command prompt is a Microsoft term. Are you actually referring to Terminal instead?

Comment: I'm just referring to bash prompt controlled by the PS1 variable.

Answer (score 1):

In bash's double-quoted strings, backslashes are preserved if the following character does not need escaping (only `"` `` ` `` `$` `\` must be escaped).

- For example, `foo="\$bar"` will result in `$bar` because `$` needs to be escaped.
- However, `foo="\%bar"` will result in `\%bar` because `%` *does not* need to be escaped.

So both `PS1="\u"` and `PS1="\\u"` will result in $PS1 having the value `\u`.

---

The code `\u` inside $PS1 is expanded to your username much later – not when assigning the variable, but every time when the prompt is shown.

Comment: So the the sequece is like so:

Comment: @gravity So the algorithm is - bash takes the first char and checks the next one. In the `\u` case it checks that `u` is just a normal char that need not to be escaped and so preserves the backslash resulting in`\u`. In the `\\u` case bash takes the second char which is now another backslash so it escapes it resulting in only one backslash from two. After that there is now `\u` and the same treatment is applied as in the first `\u` case described earlier. Is my explanation right?